# Master thermostats on a multi zone heat system

Tags: heating, thermostat

I have a 5 zone split level house with forced hot water heat. The issue I’m running into is that my house has an in-law apartment that I rent out and it occupies 2 of the 5 zones, and the other 3 are divided between my living room, bedroom and basement. The master thermostat is in my living room, and unfortunately that thermostat’s setting dictates the max temperature the rest of the thermostats can go to. I like the house around 60, and my tenant likes it around 70. We agreed to meet in the middle at 65, but unfortunately that means my boiler is heating half of my house to 65 keep her apartment comfortable because the heat needs to be set higher (raising my fuel bill); not to mention the fact that I’m uncomfortable half the time because I’m too hot. My question is whether or not I can move the master thermostat into the apartment easily, if there is a thermostat out there that will allow each zone total control over the max temperature it can be set to, or if there is a simple work around to my issue. As a side note; all 3 zones in my side of the house have digital LUX thermostats, and the apartment still has the old “turn face style” analog ones.

Comment: What does the master thermostat control, and what do the individual zone thermostats control?  (I.e. are you circulator zoned or valve zoned?)

Comment: You’ll have to forgive my lack of knowledge while I try to answer your question. My system has 2 circulators and 5 valve actuators. One of the circulators is for my domestic hot water tank and the other is obviously for the heating pipes. The circulator will kick on regardless of what zone is calling for heat and only open that zone valve, however I do know if the battery dies in the master thermostat, or if it’s switched off, the boiler won’t kick on.

Comment: Since your system has 5 valved zones you should be able to have the system circulating but not open the valves in the 3 zones you want cooler, this has been the big advantage to multi zone systems, I would look into getting updated interactive zone controls so each zone can call for heat and run the pump but only the valves in areas needing heat for that local T stat will be heating this type of controll will cost several hundred maybe less since you have a partial control system but it would quickly pay back in lower energy bills and comfort levels that you would like.